# Reorder String based on Specified Character in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way in Python to change, for example, the string "Main St & 1st St" into the string "1st St & Main St".

I know I could do something to the effect of:

```
intersection = "Main St & 1st St"
intersectionList = intersection.split(" & ")
reversedIntersection = (" & ".join(intersectionList[::-1])).strip()
```

But it just seems needlessly multi-stepped and I was wondering if there was a more efficient method, a built-in method, etc... that could accomplish the same goal better.

Comment: `reversedIntersection = (" & ".join(intersection.split(" & ")[::-1])).strip()`. There, now you have it in one step.

Comment: `'&'.join(list(reversed(s.split('&'))))`

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi, you're halfway there. The result should be a string, not a list.

Comment: @Kevin this should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I guess I had mainly just been wondering if it was really necessary to convert to a list and back to a string again or if there were simply some string manipulation technique I wasn't aware of to do it without extra conversions.   I'm guessing from the feedback though that there is no such magical method I'm not aware of.  Thanks

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi you don't need `list()`, `reversed()` already returns a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your way is to multi-stepped. The shortest way I can find to describe what you want to do is:

1. take a string
2. split it at the ampersands
3. reverse the substrings
4. write down the substrings, separating them by ampersands

That's exactly what you code does.
If you want you code to be more compact, you can leave the `.strip()` at the end since it isn't really useful and rewrite the 2nd and 3rd lines like this:

`reversedIntersection = (" & ".join(intersection.split(" & ")[::-1]))`

I don't know of any built-in method for this, since you can code it with roughly the same work it takes you to describe it and it isn't a common problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
original[original.find(" & ")+3:]+ " & " +original[:original.find(" & ")]

>>> original  = "Main St & 1st St"
>>> original.find(" & ")
7
>>> original[:original.find(" & ")]
'Main St'
>>> original[original.find(" & ")+3:]
'1st St'
>>> original[original.find(" & ")+3:]+ " & " +original[:original.find(" & ")]
'1st St & Main St'
```

or make a function

```
>>> def new(s):
...     x = " & "
...     if x not in s: return s 
...     else:
...             return s[s.find(x)+3:]+x+s[:s.find(x)]
... 
>>> new(original)
'1st St & Main St'
>>> new("2nd ave. & 6th st.")
'6th st. & 2nd ave.'
```